# How to get a specific type in a function?

Tags: php, php-7

I want to use int only for $amount but I receive double sometimes so I am checking if its int. Is there a better way to do it? My problem is another class send data to it, and I want to prevent that they should not send any type.. is it possible?

my code:

```
function finTrian($amount, $source, $trian, $realTrian, $pos = -1)
{
   if(!is_int($amount))
      return;

  if($amount < $requiredAmount)
      return "E-1019";

  $totalTrian = ($trian * $realTrian) / self::T_FACTOR;
```

...

```
}


 ?>
```

I am really having problem with this, sometimes application does not work correctly and I need to find the problem. Can someone please help me with this?

Thank you!!!

Comment: yes sir I am using php-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do it..

Just change your code like below:

from:

```
function finTrian($amount, $source, $trian, $realTrian, $pos = -1)
{
  if(!is_int($amount))
    return;

  if($amount < $requiredAmount)
    return "E-1019";
```

to:

```
function finTrian(int $amount, $source, $trian, $realTrian, $pos = -1)
{
  if($amount < $requiredAmount)
    return "E-1019";
```

the $amount parameter will be converted to int if possible. @Eiko

Types has been added in php 7:

```
bool      PHP 7.0.0
float     PHP 7.0.0
int       PHP 7.0.0
string    PHP 7.0.0
```

Comment: This will only work in php 7, int type is added in php 7 aswell

Comment: Thank you both Vural Acar and Don't Panic this is just work like charm!!!How I missed it...

Comment: This does **not** do type check. It casts! So it doesn't provide calling the function with other datatypes.

Comment: Correct, thank you Eiko, that was actually not what I ment.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to get rid of the type check.

If you specify the type in the function as in the other answer:

```
function finTrian(int $amount, $source, $trian, $realTrian, $pos = -1) { ... }
```

the `$amount` parameter will be converted to int if possible.

So calling it with `$amount = 3.8` will just call the function with `finTrian(3, ...)`

Note: it will be casted to 3, not to 4. This is fundamentally different than the type check you had in your question!

Comment: @Don'tPanic Good catch. Does this actually use anyone (consistently)?

Comment: Not sure, but I'm glad it's there. Type declarations wouldn't be as useful otherwise, IMO.